# Hibernate SQL query matching more than one members of an ElementCollection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have Pojo mapped with JPA annotations like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "record")
public class SearchRecord {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int id;
private String vidName;
@ElementCollection
private List<String> videoLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and would like to run a Hibernate query that filters out all SearchRecords that match/contain 1..n videoLabels. (only objects that match all of the videoLabels)

I was able to search for SearchRecords that match a single label by running the following query:

```
String labelCar = "Car";
String labelPerson = "Person";
TypedQuery<SearchRecord> query = em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM SearchRecord b JOIN b.videoLabels l WHERE l = :param1",SearchRecord.class);
query.setParameter("param1", labelCar);
List<SearchRecord> results = query.getResultList();
```

But how can I execute a query filtering out all SearchResults matching Car and Person?

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT a FROM SearchRecord a JOIN a.labels b JOIN a.labels c WHERE b.name = 'Car' and c.name = 'Person'
```